# Typerror: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial' error. When trying to use class-based views and crispy forms

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

This issue has been bugging me for days and I couldn't find an answer anywhere, I even suspect it`s actually a bug, but as I'm a django beginner who has just started to play around with class-based views I figured I might be doing something wrong.

So, I created a simple UpdateView with LoginRequiredMixin to update my model and it works well, but if I try to customize the forms.py to use crispy forms I get and error.

Here`s my code:

**models.py**

```
class Profile(TimeStampedModel):
    LANGUAGES = (
        ('pt_BR', 'Português(Brasil)'),
        ('en_US', 'English(USA)'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
    language = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=LANGUAGES, default=LANGUAGES[0][0])

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('edit-profile')
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('language',)
        labels = {
            'language': 'Idioma',
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = ProfileForm

    template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user.profile
```

**So far so good, everything works if I generate a {{ form.as_p }} in my template.**

Now if I begin to customize my ProfileForm class in forms.py by inserting:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('language',)
        labels = {
            'language': 'Idioma',
        }

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

#       self.helper = FormHelper()
#     ... continue crispy form setup...
```

Even before I instantiate any object from crispy form, just by inserting these two lines:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

If I try loading the page I get the following TypeError:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'
```

Now, from my understading, just by declaring __init__ and super() inside it without any additional argument, the class should behave just like before but instead I get the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\myvenv\lib\site-
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "\myvenv\lib\site-
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "\myvenv\lib\site-
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "\myvenv\lib\site-
packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\myvenv\lib\site-
packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 56, in dispatch
    return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, 
**kwargs)
  File "\myvenv\lib\site-
packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\myvenv\lib\site-
packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 236, in get
    return super(BaseUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\myvenv\lib\site-
packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 174, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "\myvenv\lib\site-
packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 93, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "\myvenv\lib\site-
packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 45, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'
```

I'm using Python 3.6.2 and Django 1.11.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've changed the signature of the form so that it takes no arguments. But forms need to accept arguments - initial, data, etc. You need to ensure that it continues to accept the arguments it is expecting, and then pass all of them up to the super class method. The normal way to do this is to accept `*args, **kwargs`.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It works! I was misled by the new Python 3 syntax which allows me to use super().__init__(), I though I could omit *args and **kwargs in the def too. Thanks!